# redirect GET form to user friendly URL

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I have a form that redirects my data using GET as a method to this page (seccions/search.php) wich redirects me to:

```
http://host/seccions/search.php?search_term_string=([^/]*)&search_term_on=([^/]*)
```

And i would like to be redirected once submitted to this other pattern:

```
http://host/empresas/categoria/$1/poblacio/$2/
```

I'm trying to accomplish that via htaccess (as I don't see other easy ways) I try to redirect the ugly url to the pretty one, that gets later on, on the htaccess converted to the proper url pattern using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^seccions/search.php?search_term_string=([^/]*)&search_term_on=([^/]*)$ empresas/categoria/$1/poblacio/$2/ [L]
RewriteRule ^empresas/categoria/([^/]*)/poblacio/([^/]*)$ seccions/search.php?que=$1&on=$2 [L]
```

(I know I'm changing the param names and the .php search page is already prepared for different $_GET names)

but once the form gets submitted it just goes to the ugly url with the GET params in it.

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd rule is correct but 1st won't work because you cannot match query string in a `RewriteRule`. You will need to use `THE_REQUEST` variable in a `RewriteCond` to avoid looping:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /puntvallesgit/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search_term_string=([^\s&]+)&search_term_on=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ empresas/categoria/%1/poblacio/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^empresas/categoria/([^/]+)/poblacio/([^/]+)$ seccions/search.php?que=$1&on=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: if that should be working without touching code, for some reason it's not :S

Comment: If I search in the form it redirects me to "http://localhost/puntvallesgit/seccions/search.php?search_term_string=Articles+nous&search_term_on=Agramunt" the expected one would be "localhost/puntvalles/categoria/Articles+nous/poblacio/Agramunt" and I do have other conditions for the same url pattern but with 1 or 2 params instead of the 2 of before (for the breadcrumbs) I'll post a proper reply so you can see all the HTACCESS code related to those links.

Comment: ok now it "works" but it kills my localhost subfolder, redirecting me to "http://localhost/empresas/categoria/Articles+erotics/poblacio/Agramunt/" instead of "http://localhost/puntvallesgit/empresas/categoria/Articles+erotics/poblacio/Agramunt/"

Comment: Did you forget to mention `/puntvallesgit/` in your question?

Comment: I might've omiited it, as it "should" not affect in localhost, all other rewrites don't need to be specified anything related to the working "root" folder, as when it's online it wont be using that subfolder. I'm gonna test now

Comment: Yes as per my latest update you will need `RewriteBase /puntvallesgit/` or `RewriteBase /` as per your case.

Comment: seems not to work either with the RewriteBase base still redirects without the /puntvallesgit/ subdirectory

Comment: yes i ctrl+f5 each time and I ment it still redirects me to the path ignoring the /puntvallesgit folder

Comment: Did you note that I removed `/` before `empresas` in first rule?

Comment: I did not notice it, it does work now. I appreciate it man, thanks

Comment: just a question, if I would want those 2 params or either one of those 2, could also be done like this?

Comment: I also noticed that it now redirects me to google (as a search) when i enter localhost/puntvallesgit, but it works OK with localhost/puntvallesgit/

Comment: This comment section is already too long for further discussions. I would suggest trying out something by looking at this example for `either of 2 params` requirement. If it doesn't work feel free to post a new question and we'll attend.